# Symfony 4 several forms (steps) for one entity

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I have table and entity class with multiple (30) fields. I want to build no one big form, but for example 3 forms (10 fields each), that will save following fields in the same record in the table.
This is simple to do in pure PHP or other simpler framework where I do it manually. How to do this in Symfony, where many things are more automated? 
I look for a general tip, which approach to use.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to take a look at https://github.com/craue/CraueFormFlowBundle it does exactly what you want: creates multi step forms for large forms. I have a pretty good experience with it, works with Symfony 4.

Please [check](https://www.craue.de/symfony-playground/en/CraueFormFlow/) the demos as well.

Comment: There is a problem unresolved problem with mapped => false fields - I don't recoomend this bundle

Answer (score -1):

Hey for building form you can use [symfony form component](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/form.html) just creat a php class that represent you entity and dont forget the `@ORM\Entity()` annotation.
Then just use `php bin/console generate:doctrine:form App:Entity` to generate a form type class by using the metadata mapping of a given entity class.

It depends on your model logic, you can decouple your form to one parent form, and other's childrens forms...then for each child `form type` you call it like this:

```
class ParentType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('title')
            ->add('summary', Child1Type::class)
            ->add('content', Child2Type::class)
            ...
     }
}
```

And after that just go back to you controller:

```
public function editAction(Request $request, entity $entity)
{
    $form = $this->formFactory->createForm(ParentType::class, $entity);
    if ($form->isValid() && $form->isSubmitted()) {
       //perform some action
    }
}
```

You can also use **DTOs** for good pratice. It's better solution to decouple your form, take a look to these articles: https://williamdurand.fr/2013/12/16/enforcing-data-encapsulation-with-symfony-forms/
http://verraes.net/2013/04/decoupling-symfony2-forms-from-entities/

Comment: It is probably not what I am looking for.

Comment: @InforMat Caould you explain more what you are looking for.

Comment: I solved this: simply I defined something like Form1Type, Form2Type and Form3Type classes, in each I defined only third part of fields from an entity class, and all fields that are used in second and third form type had to be optional - something like that I looked for. Your answer is just basic example from documentation.

Comment: Ok happy for your feddback, wish you think it solved your problem or was the most helpful in finding your solution. Thank you. Cheers! –